# Why is my cipher correct in most places and incorrect in others?

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

Hello I'm fairly new to programming in python and have challenged myself to create a Caesar cipher that takes a coded message and outputs a decoded message. For some reason part of the message is decoded correctly but other parts of the message are not and I can't figure out why that is. For example if I input the coded message Lipps${svph% and set the distance value for the cipher to 4 then the message should come out Hello world! but instead it comes out ello²world±. Any help in figuring out why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

```
distance = int(input("Enter the distance value: "))
plainText = ""
for ch in code:
    ordvalue = ord(ch)
    cipherValue = ordvalue - distance
    if cipherValue < ord('a'):
        cipherValue = ord('z') - \
                      (distance - (ord('a') - ordvalue - 1))
    plainText += chr(cipherValue)
print(plainText)
```

Comment: it prints Helllo world! if you remove the `if cipherValue ..` bloc

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the if statement the ord() values for lowercase letters are infact higher than the capitalised letters so you should be using

```
if cipherValue < ord('A'):
    cipherValue = ord('Z') - \
                  (distance - (ord('A') - ordvalue - 1))
```

however this still wont work for non letter characters like '!' and ' ' you can limit this warp around behaviour to just letters with

```
if cipherValue < ord('A') and cipherValue > ord('Z'):
    cipherValue = ord('Z') - \
                  (distance - (ord('A') - ordvalue - 1))
```

This will output Hello world! as intended